# Удалить строки начинающиеся с

Tags: c#

В .txt есть строки, которые начинаются с `"{"`. Как их удалить и оставить только пустую строку. Если количество строк в .txt 500, то останется одна.

```
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines("test1.txt");
foreach (var lines1 in file1)
{
    if (lines1.StartsWith("{"))
    {
        string text = lines1.Replace(lines1, "");
        //Console.WriteLine(lines1);
        File.WriteAllText("test1", text);
    }
}
```

Comment: выбрать все строки , не начинающиеся с этого символа, и перезаписать документ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не до конца понял, что именно должно остаться в файле. Поэтому сделал универсальный метод.

```
    var fileList = File.ReadAllLines("test1.txt").ToList();
    for (var i = fileList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (fileList[i].StartsWith("{"))
            fileList.RemoveAt(i); //Удаление строки целиком
            //fileList[i] = String.Empty; //Оставляем строку, но делаем ее пустой
    }

    File.WriteAllLines("test1.txt", fileList);
```

Суть следующая:

- Читаем файл построчно и делаем удобный для редактирования `List`.
- Перебираем циклом `for` данный `List`и и ищем подходящую нам строку.
- Если строка подходит, то удаляем ее из `List` (`fileList.RemoveAt(i)`) /
  заменяем ее на нужное (`fileList[i] = String.Empty;`).
- Получившийся список перезаписываем в нужный файл.

Только не стоит забывать о проверках (на отсутствие файла к примеру, или на отсутствие изменений (что бы не записывать по сотню раз в файл одну и туже информацию)), но это уже думаю сами без проблем сделаете.

Comment: при таком подходе (`fileList.RemoveAt(i)`) что будет если две строки подряд будут начинаться с `{`?

Comment: Думаю стоит начинать с конца массива. **Вы так рискуете пропустить строки при удалении**. С заменой строки на пустую будет всё работать нормально.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Удаление элемента из списка будет перемещать все элементы, расположенные за ним. Лучше тогда уж использовать связный список или фильтровать с помощью `Where`

Comment: @Андрей В данном вопросе я считаю это уже лишнее. Автору вполне подойдет `LINQ` из другого ответа, если просто надо удалить строки. Я данный вариант написал как исправление того, что уже сам автор написал. По поводу смещения - если не будет дальнейшего обращение по индексу к нужной строке, то это в данном случае не критично, ведь список читается (уже) с последней строки и мы смещаем то, что уже проверили и нам по сути не нужно. Ваше предложение понадобится, если мы дальше будет работать с этим списком и нам нужна его правильная последовательность.

Comment: Все гут, но есть один минус, а именно, когда код срабатывает то он, вместо этих строк которые удаляет, не оставляет эти все места пустыми, то есть будет строка, после нее места свободного много, потом далее строка и о5 много места...

Comment: @Tode Если вы дадите пример файла, который надо проверить и то, что должно получиться, то попробую поправить ответ. Уточните это пожалуйста в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да просто, в `.txt` записан цикл от и до (`,` как энтер )
`0,{1,{2,{3,{4,{5,{6,{7,{8,{9,10`
после работы кода будет так
`0 здесь пусто, вместо чисел(1-9)10`

Comment: @Tode Подождите, но я ведь в коде указал строку `fileList[i] = String.Empty;` Она текущую строку, которая начинается с `{` заменит на пустоту. Это разве не подходит вам?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне кажись, если не ошибаюсь, то студия выдавала ерор, индесы кажись были вне границы, или что то типа этого

Comment: @Tode В данном примере у вас должно быть либо `fileList.RemoveAt(i);` либо `fileList[i] = String.Empty;`. Первый вариант удалит строку целиком, второй вариант заменит ее на пустую строку. Оставлять и две строки сразу не стоит. Вот я вас написал [код](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zJsHYf), снизу можете посмотреть результат вывода. Ошибок быть не должно (особенно при замене строки пустотой).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прекрасно работает ваш код, но, одну детальку можете добавить( я просто после результата решил ее изменить) а именно, чтобы не просто удалить все строки, и вместо них оставить пустоту, а пустоту сократить, чтобы осталась только !!одна!! пустая строка))

Comment: @Tode Создайте некую переменную `bool`, в цикле проверяйте, если строка содержит символ, то проверяем переменную, если она `true`, то строку удаляем, а если `false` - строку заменяем пустотой. [Набросал](https://dotnetfiddle.net/85HIyp) пример.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прекрасно))

Answer (score 4):

С помощью LINQ выбираем все строки, не начинающиеся с нужного нам символа. 
Потом удаляем файл и перезаписываем его. Как подсказали ниже, не обязательно удалять файл

```
var exLines = lines.Where(l => !l.StartsWith("{")); // выбор всех строк в IEnumerable<string>
File.Delete("file"); // удаление файла 
File.AppendAllLines("file.txt", exLines); // создание и записывание файла
```

Comment: Ответ станет лучше, если добавить минимальное описание (например, Ваш комментарий скопировать в ответ).

Comment: Удалять файл не обязательно, можно просто перезаписать его: `File.WriteAllLines()`

Comment: @default locale, дополнил )

Comment: @Андрей, да, точно, вы правы :)