# Добавить строку richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Стояла задача сформировать некий файл из нескольких путём сложения, вычитания, деления и т.д.
Но в конце него я хочу добавить одну строку, не могу понять, как это сделать..

```
private void btCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TXT.Text = "";
        int b = -1;
        string txt = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lBLN.Count; i++)
        {
            int a = b + 1;
            b = GetB(a);
            int n = RB1.Checked ? b - a + 1 : 2;
            double xa = lBLN[i].xa;
            double xb = lBLN[i].xb;
            double ya = lBLN[i].ya;
            double yb = lBLN[i].yb;
            double dx = xb - xa;
            double dy = yb - ya;
            double dx1 = lDAT[b].x;
            double dy1 = dy * dx1 / dx;
            double cx = dx1 / (n - 1);
            double cy = dy1 / (n - 1);
            double x,y;
            for (int k = a; k <= b; k++)
            {
                if (RB1.Checked)
                {
                    x = xa + (k - a) * cx;
                    y = ya + (k - a) * cy;
                }
                else
                {
                    dx1 = lDAT[k].x;
                    dy1 = dy * dx1 / dx;
                    x = xa + dx1;

                    y = ya + dy1;
                }
                txt += "" + x + " " + y + " " + lDAT[k].z + "\n";


            }
        }

        TXT.Text = txt.Replace(',', '.');
        btSave.Focus();
    }
```

Тут формируется то, что мне нужно в richtextbox

```
 txt += "" + x + " " + y + " " + lDAT[k].z + "\n";
```

Я хочу добавить всего одну строчку снизу
"" + xb + " " + yb + " " + lDAT[b].z + "\n";
Но если я это приписываю к txt+=, то эта строка у меня каждый раз (да и понятно, почему). Как мне её в самый конец затолкать?

PS. Задача, описанная выше - решилась, но возник вопрос.
Необходимо удалить сначала одну строку из моего richtextbox, а затем только добавить нужную нам строку.

Richtextbox формируется так: `txt += "" + x + " " + y + " " + lDAT[k].z + "\n";`
Затем, после выполнения цикла я хочу удалить строку последнюю. пишу код: 
`string lastLine = TXT.Lines.Last();
 TXT.Lines = TXT.Lines.Where(x => x != lastLine).ToArray();` , но удаления не происходит, так как когда выполнялся цикл, у нас каретка бежала вниз "\n" и получается пустая строка. Если мы перед этим кодом, также вне цикла, добавим вручную строчку `txt += "" + xb + " " + yb + " " + lDAT[b].z`, то она не появится, так как код для удаления выполнится. Как избавиться от проблемы с кареткой?

Comment: объявить нужные переменные перед циклом (а не в нем) и написать `"" + xb + " " + yb + " " + lDAT[b].z + "\n";` за циклом

Comment: есть же метод `Append`

Comment: @tCode чем может помочь `Append`, если в данном коде возможно дописать стрингу только в цикле, что не нужно (как я понял)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ))

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Можно вопрос? А возможно ли удалить последнюю строчку, например, из моего txt, который я формирую?

Comment: Или заменить её на ту, что я добавляю

Comment: Можно...вам поможет [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706114/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц перелопатил много чего, извиняюсь, не понимаю просто. Советовали это: TXT.Text = txt.Remove(txt.LastIndexOf("\n")); -  но не работает..

Comment: суть в том, чтобы считать текущий файл в массив строк, потом сделать все, что вам нужно с этими строка, и записать заново (в тот же или другой) файл

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Ответ нашёлся, но из за каретки "\n" не удаляется строка string lastLine = TXT.Lines.Last();
            TXT.Lines = TXT.Lines.Where(x => x != lastLine).ToArray(); Если я сначала добавляю строку  txt += "" + xbb + " " + ybb + " " + lDAT[b].z; а потом код выше, то тогда этой строки нет, она удаляется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если знаете, как обойти этот момент..

Comment: немного не понятно что вы перерделали, а что оставили, обновите пожалуйста код в опросе

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Я обновил вопрос выше. После P.S всё описал

Answer (score 0):

В общем я не стал делать красиво, хотя может следовало бы, просто продублировал объявление переменных перед циклом, оставив и в цикле то же самое.

```
private void btCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TXT.Text = "";
        int b = -1;
        string txt = "";
        int ii=0;
        double xbb = lBLN[ii].xb;
        double ybb = lBLN[ii].yb;
        for (int i = 0; i < lBLN.Count; i++)
        {
            int a = b + 1;
            b = GetB(a);
            int n = RB1.Checked ? b - a + 1 : 2;
            double xa = lBLN[i].xa;
            double xb = lBLN[i].xb;
            double ya = lBLN[i].ya;
            double yb = lBLN[i].yb;
            double dx = xb - xa;
            double dy = yb - ya;
            double dx1 = lDAT[b].x;
            double dy1 = dy * dx1 / dx;
            double cx = dx1 / (n - 1);
            double cy = dy1 / (n - 1);
            double x,y;
            for (int k = a; k <= b; k++)
            {
                if (RB1.Checked)
                {
                    x = xa + (k - a) * cx;
                    y = ya + (k - a) * cy;
                }
                else
                {
                    dx1 = lDAT[k].x;
                    dy1 = dy * dx1 / dx;
                    x = xa + dx1;

                    y = ya + dy1;
                }
                txt += "" + x + " " + y + " " + lDAT[k].z + "\n";


            }
        }
        txt += "" + xbb + " " + ybb + " " + lDAT[b].z + "\n";
        TXT.Text = txt.Replace(',', '.');
        btSave.Focus();
    }
```

Ну и дополнение. Проблема с удалением каретки (удаление появившейся пустой строки решается через Trim). В случае моей задачи `TXT.Text = txt.Replace(',', '.').Trim('\n');`